# Programatically change keyboard from custom android keyboard

Tags: android, ime, android-input-method

I have created an android custom keyboard.  After pressing a button on it, I'd like it to change the keyboard back to the previous keyboard, presumable using `InputMethodManager.setInputMethod(IBinder token, String id);`

However, I can't work out where to get the token from - using `getCurrentInputBinding().getConnectionToken()` doesn't work.

Does anyone know where to find the token?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the `switchInputMethod(String id)` method works a treat - no need for that token.

Comment: Where You find this method?

Comment: I can't remember where I found it, but it's available on classes that extend InputMethodService

Comment: i googling so more but don't get success in to get this named method.
ok what ever it was leave it. but please tell me you got success in change the keyboard to custom keyboard? I have an issue on that subject,is i want to change the theme of keyboard so just want to know that how to do that by Programatically have? have any Idea? LIKE THIS https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.phone.trial&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnRvdWNodHlwZS5zd2lmdGtleS5waG9uZS50cmlhbCJd

Comment: How to get the previous keyboard ID in the custom keyboard??

Answer (score 1):

You get the token from the view by `view.getWindowToken()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Method to get Token and activate last used Keyboard

```
 private fun switchToLastKeyboard() {
        try {
            val imm: InputMethodManager =
                this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            val token = this.window.window!!.attributes.token
            //imm.setInputMethod(token, LATIN);
            imm.switchToLastInputMethod(token)
        } catch (t: Throwable) { // java.lang.NoSuchMethodError if API_level<11
            Log.i("TAG", "onCreateInputView: Throwable " + t.message)
        }

    }
```